# Is it possible to cancel a synchronous NSURLConnection from another thread?

Tags: cocoa, nsurlconnection, synchronous

My design is in a spot of bother, mainly because a requirement of it is to be able to support cancellation of NSURLConnections that are in progress.

I've heard plenty of people say that you cannot send the cancel message to NSURLConnections objects that are running in synchronous mode, but is this solely because of the logistics of it? For example, if an NSURLConnection is loading synchronously, then the cancel message sent on the same thread wouldn't be received by the connection object until after the connection has finished anyway.

What I'm hoping is that it is possible to send a SYNCHRONOUS NSURLConnection object the cancel message from another thread.

Does anyone know if this is possible or have tried it before?

Regards,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

No, it isn't!  Quite simply because the class method to which you start a synchronous NSURLConnection doesn't return a connection object (upon which you would call the cancel method) - it returns an NSData object instead!